# How to make iAd in iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, iad, adbannerview

Currently i am working in an iAd iPhone application.  Using `ADBannerView` to make it, I have one URL for show advertisement in iPhone apps, but I don't know how to integrate this.

I tried this:

```
IBOutlet ADBannerView *adView;
adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50,ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32,nil];
adView.delegate=self;
```

Then I want where I insert the URL to show iAds.

Comment: See above, now i edit my question for your reference.

Comment: did you try googling or searching apple site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apple has 2 sample codes which demonstrates the iAd implementation in any iOS apps, have you gone through these..

[iAdSuite](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010198) & [iAdInterstitialSuite](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdInterstitialSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010627)

download these sample apps, review them and try to implement it in your app.